# Swift: Override Objective-c extension (anonymous) properties from subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've spent quite a bit of time figuring this out..and haven't found any success.

Put simply, I need a swift subclass of an objective c class to be able to override a certain property declared in the .m file inside of an extension. How would I do this? Essentially the property needs to be replaced with a custom subclass.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
}
@end

//SomeClass.m
@interface SomeClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView scrollView;
@end


//Swift class
class NewClass: SomeClass {

let scrollViewSubclass = MyScrollView()

override var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
return scrollViewSubclass
    }
}
```

Something like that.. just not sure how to do it. I can't even override scrollView because the swift subclass doesn't know it exists!

Comment: You can't do that because it would violate the LSP - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle but as long as the subclass you want to use is a subclass for UIScrollView then you can just assign an instance of that subclass to the existing property

Comment: So without going into the objective c file, how would I assign that this property.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've been able to see the property this way: var newScrollView: UIScrollView {

        return self.valueForKey("scrollView") as! UIScrollView
    }

Comment: But the question is how I would replace that property with my subclass of scrollview without going into the .m file

Comment: yes, you can do that.  You can't access it directly because it is kind-of a private property. I say kind-of because Objective-C doesn't have private properties, but you can hide it from casual inspection by omitting it from the .h

Comment: You can't replace the property, you simply assign an instance of `MyScrollView` to the existing property - `self.setValue(myScollViewInstance forKey:"scrollView")`

Comment: gotcha, so is there a way to change that super scrollView to a subclass of scrollView from swift?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105852/discussion-between-paulw11-and-yichenbman).